# KeePass2 and KeePassX, which is more secure?

Tags: password, security, keepass, keepassx

I use KeePass2 on Windows and KeePassX on Linux. I understand the arguments between the two on database compatibility and cross-platform performance. What I'm curious about is whether either one is more or less secure.

In the following examples I'm running KeePass2 and KeePassX downloaded straight from the Ubuntu repositories.

I generated a password using KeePassX, and pasted it into a fake entry in both programs. Notice the different evaluations in password security.

**KeePassX:**

[image: KeePassX:112 Bit]

**KeePass2:**

[image: KeePass2: 75 Bits]

Next I made a password myself by quickly mashing some keyboard keys. As before, KeePassX returns a higher count than KeePass2 (like it almost always does).

**KeePassX:**

[image: KeePassX: 56 Bit]

**KeePass2:**

[image: KeePass2: 30 Bits]

Which is correct? Are the two programs using different algorithms to determine security? Which is more trustworthy?

Also, do the two programs use different encryption methods for their databases? Is either more secure?

Comment: You probably should ask this on [security.se]. That's where I'd expect to find experts. Also see http://security.stackexchange.com/q/2687.  And the graphic comparing other password strength checkers in https://blogs.dropbox.com/tech/2012/04/zxcvbn-realistic-password-strength-estimation/.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you probably should ask this on Information Security.